# Setting Bi-directional relationship with Spring data jpa one to many with RestController

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have a `RestController` which accepts the `Order` entity and the `Order` entity has `OrderLineItem` with `One-to-Many` relationship. I have set up the scaffolding code as below in the `Order` entity.

My question is, why do I need to set up the biderectional relationship inside the Controller class. When I send the payload, the link from the OrderLineItem does not populate the foreign key column

The Payload:

```
{
        "totalPrice": 40000,
        "orderDate": "2020-06-16",
        "lineItems": [
            {
                "qty": 1,
                "price": 55000
            }
        ]
    }
```

```
//I do not understand the need for this when the payload itself contains the order and OrderLineItems. Is this necessary?
order.getLineItems().forEach(order::addOrderLineItem);
```

```
@Setter
@Getter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "orderId")
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ApiModel
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
    @Column(name="order_id")
    private long orderId;

    @Max(value = 50000, message = "Order price should be more than 25k and less than 50K")
    @Min(value = 25000, message = "Order price should be more than 25k and less than 50K")
    @ApiParam("total order price")
    private double totalPrice;

    @NotNull(message = "Order date cannot be null")
    @ApiModelProperty("order date")
    private LocalDate orderDate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = ALL)
    private Set<OrderLineItem> lineItems = new HashSet<>();

    //scaffolding method to set the bidirectional mapping
    public void addOrderLineItem(OrderLineItem orderLineItem){
        orderLineItem.setOrder(this);
        this.lineItems.add(orderLineItem);
    }

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="line_items")
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
public class OrderLineItem {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Setter @Getter
    private int id;

    @Setter @Getter
    private int qty;

    @Setter @Getter
    private double price;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="order_id")
    @OnDelete(action = CASCADE)
    @JsonIgnore
    @Setter
    private Order order;
}
```

The Code from the `OrderController` class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/orders")
@AllArgsConstructor
@Api("Order API - Version 1")
public class OrderController {

    //@Autowired
    private OrderService orderService;

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @PostMapping
    public Order createOrder(@RequestBody @Valid Order order){
        //set the biderection mapping
        order.getLineItems().forEach(order::addOrderLineItem);
        return this.orderService.saveOrder(order);
    }
```

Comment: The `forEach` does this: `orderLineItem.setOrder(this)`. json does not include object references so you have to make them before you persist the order so the foreign keys will be  set and you don't get database constraint exceptions.

Comment: Do you mean that, we need to set the reference from the child entity manually.

Comment: I think that is the case you need to set the reference in the child entity. I don't think that JSON deserialization will do that for you and the persistence layer needs it to be done in order to set the FK.